# Importing Module python

Tags: python, linux, alchemyapi

I have added:

```
export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/home/twittercap/alchemyapi"
```

to my ~/.profile file (ubuntu server environment) and it shows when I run

```
import sys
print sys.path
```

but it won't let me import the module using

```
from alchemyapi import AlchemyAPI
```

(which I can when running from within the directory.

Any help is appreciated.

**Update:**
I can now `import alchemyapi` but `import alchemyapi.AlchemyAPI` returns `ImportError: No module named AlchemyAPI` (but there is!)

Comment: Did you `source ~/.profile`?

Comment: What is in `/home/twittercap/alchemiapi` ? Is _there_ a module `achemyapi` ? Maybe you need to put just `/home/twittercap` into `PYTHONPATH` ?

Comment: sys.path.append('/home/twittercap')

Comment: Thanks for your response - have git cloned (github.com/AlchemyAPI/alchemyapi_python) and then renamed it to alchemyapi, I have run source and sys.path.append doesn't solve it either (it is already in sys path) – I have also attempted placing /home/twittercap into pythonpath/sys to no avail.

Comment: on my mac I am able to just run `sys.path.insert(1, '/home/twittercap')` and it works

Comment: Many thanks for your Suggestions

Answer (score 0):

**Resolved:** Git cloned again and didn't rename - either the rename messed it up, or else the files corrupted the first time - thanks for your suggestions though!